# How to preload a sound file and feed it to flashplayer?

Tags: javascript, flash

I it possible to prelowad a sound file with javascript (or gwt) and feed it to a flashplayer without a server roundtrip?

I would like to play the sound right after a uses clisks a button on a web site without a delay caused by server roundtrip.

Comment: Probably not "without a server roundtrip", but I think it should be possible to make this roundtrip between the time that page loads and the time the button is clicked, which then should reduce (or eliminate) the delay. (Do Flash HTTP requests go through the browser, or does it use its own fetcher?)

Comment: I would like to preload it with javascript - put it into a buffer and feet a buffer to flash

Comment: why don't you just have Flash preload the sound upon loading the swf, then just have it play on click? Since it's already loaded into your swf, you're not having to pass anything into flash via javascript. This is the type of stuff Flash is GOOD at, so why not use it?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the path to the sound file into flash using flashvars. I bet you could even pass in the sound as encoded string data with flashvars, then decode it in flash and load it into a sound object.

Answer (score 0):

or even better. if you made the flash audio player then embed the sound into the player. But if you load the sound (using a embed tag) then it will be cached by the browser and when flash tries to load it it will find it in the cache. but the right headers must be set in order to avoid the server round trip completely